# Do URL redirects negatively affect SEO when part of a site restructuring?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, pagerank, link-juice

I understand that no 'Link Juice' is lost, when implementing a 301 Redirect for the purposes of redirecting from `http` to `https` prefixes.

What about redirects, when a site goes under a restructure?

Lets say I have the following URL:

```
www.example.com/product-category-a/
```

The site's inventory then increases, to warrant a broader Product Category; resulting in `product-category-a` being 'demoted' to a Child Category.  As a such, the URL has been altered to the following:

```
www.example.com/new-broader-product-category/product-category-a/
```

If someone clicks through, via a 3rd party site, they will initially be taken to `www.example.com/product-category-a/` and then redirected to the restructured URL.  In doing so, would there be any 'Link Juice' lost?

Comment: Nope. Your fine. Same rules apply. Of course, the original URL is dropped and the new one is indexed. There is a difference there. Assuming the content is the same, the new URL will be taken into account for semantic meaning. If the page changes then the new page is evaluated. It is as if one page is dropped and another indexed. Any differences will be taken into account. Cheers!!

Comment: This is the type of question I would have expected to have had asked and answered here many times, however I can't find a duplicate.

Comment: @closetnoc ... *"original URL is dropped and the new one is indexed"*  Are you saying that once the '301 Redirect' code has been inserted into the `.htaccess` file (or other relevant file(s)), then search engines will eventually drop the old URL completely from their index, replacing with the new one?  I was under the impression, a '301 Redirect' would simply keep the old URL and when clicked on, load the replacement URL.  Just like when you go to some websites, it starts to load and then annoyingly, you would get redirected to an page full of adverts.

Comment: @closetnoc ... Once search engines have dropped the old URL and replaced it with the new URL, would it be ok to then remove the relevant '301 Redirect' code or does it need to be permanently kept within the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @Craig Yes. You can remove it. If you have any valuable links to any URL, you may want to consider retaining the redirect. Otherwise, if you do not care, then remove them without issue. I did this to restructure a site where I did not care about any links. I redirected over 800k URLs for at least 6 months then removed the old URLs. It all worked out well.

Comment: @Craig There are several redirects. A 301 replaces one URLs with the other in search engines. A 302 does not. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link juice will be retained but there will be a "dance" in the rankings but it will pick back up as long as the proper redirect is implemented. You also need to dofollow the link to retain the juice.